# Solving for X and Y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation - 
$ 6xy + 9x - 4y = 6 $

This might be basic , but I'm actually stuck on how to find X and Y from here . How do I make this into a quadratic equation so I can solve from there ? Can I get a hint ? Thanks !

Comment: did you think of rearranging as $x=\frac{4y+6}{6y+9}$, does this help any further?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can rewrite the equation to:

$$ -6xy-4y+9x=6 \iff (-6x-4)y=6-9x$$

and then solve for $y$

$$y=\frac{6-9x}{-6x-4}=\frac{3(2-3x)}{2(-2-3x)}=\frac{3(3x-2)}{2(3x+2)}$$